# Ford Ranger 3.0 TDCI XLT - Fifth Gear Problems

Tags: ford, manual-transmission, shifting, ranger

I have a Ford Ranger 3.0 TDCI XLT 2007 Model. I can get all my gears except fifth gear. I have checked the hydraulic clutch and bled it. Still the same problem. After driving with it, it also started giving trouble in 3rd gear. What is causing this problem??

Comment: A worn out gear train?  Loose linkage connections causing slight misalignment in the shifter controls? Have you been in an accident recently?  How many miles on the truck?